# Regular Expression for doubles pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)");

Tags: java

I'm using

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)");
```

But I want it to output what I input for e.g., 1.3 would come out 1.3
instead it comes out as 1.30000 (with 5 zeros after it).

Can someone break this down and explain it to me a little better.
Thanks!

Comment: pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)"); sorry i linked one I was trying to fix... this is the original one I have in my project.

Comment: \d+ will match 1 or more digits.  so if your string had 5 digits after the "." it will match that.

Comment: ...and to skip the '0's you'll need something like `\d+\.[1-9]+`

Comment: I tried using pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.[1-9]+"); and its giving me the same 5 zeros after ... I'm still rusty with regular expression so I'm trying to under how to read this as I input

Comment: I got it figured out with formatting the output. Thank you guys!